# Getting started with midijs

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm having trouble with getting started with midijs. The initial examples don't output any sound. How do I get started with playing a single MIDI note in the browser?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="./js/MIDI/AudioDetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./js/MIDI/LoadPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./js/MIDI/Plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./js/MIDI/Player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./js/Window/DOMLoader.XMLHttp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- extras -->
      <script src="./inc/Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./inc/base64binary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
<body>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    MIDI.loadPlugin({
        soundfontUrl: "./soundfont/",
        instrument: "acoustic_grand_piano",
        callback: function() {
            var delay = 0; // play one note every quarter second
            var note = 50; // the MIDI note
            var velocity = 127; // how hard the note hits
            // play the note
            MIDI.programChange(0, 1); // Load "synth_drum" (118) into channel 0
            MIDI.setVolume(0, 127);
            MIDI.noteOn(0, note, velocity, delay);
            MIDI.noteOff(0, note, delay + 0.75);
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

I've set up the MIDI part, but I don't know how to get the music to play from Chrome.

Comment: Step one would be to show us what you have tried so far.  It isn't possible to help you when we're not sure where you're stuck.  There are a thousand possible answers to your question... don't leave us guessing, show us what you've done.  Otherwise it could be anything from a syntax error to your speakers being unplugged.  And, what browser?

Comment: Edited, using Chrome.